# Indefinite integral question

Tags: real-analysis

Hi could you help me with the following

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2 (\sin x)^{2/3}}$$

How can I show that this integral is convergent?
Thank you.

Comment: That's a definite, not an indefinite, integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are interested in
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2((\sin x)^2)^{1/3}},$$
then you cannot show the integral is convergent, since it is in fact divergent. Informally, the function blows up too rapidly near $0$ for  the integral to exist. If you want to do a formal comparison, do so for example with $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$, which diverges. The problem is that $\int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac{dx}{x^2}$ blows up as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ from the right.